# I have installed ds9 on linux but the command is not found when I just write 'ds9' in my terminal

Tags: linux, ds9

I just installed ds9 on linux, and I know it's correctly installed because when I write 'conda install ds9' in my terminal, it says that "All the requested packages are already installed". Then, when I just write 'ds9' in my terminal, it says 'bash: ds9: command not found...' . What is going on ? Does someone know how I can open ds9 ?

Comment: ***What is going on ?*** Maybe its installed in a path that is not listed in your PATH environment variable. You may want to investigate your OS filesystem.

Comment: How **did** you install it? Trying to reproduce your problem I got `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:  -ds9`

Comment: Further to this a 5 year old post suggests that `ds9` is not available because it was superseded.